# How to resolve "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, nonetype

So, I'm wanting to do some visualization on EPA environmental media sampling data for PFAS. I'm using pandas and matplotlib for this. I've got the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

inputpath="CHI"

col_for_analysis=["Environmental Media Name", "Year", "Result Measure Value (ppt)"]

dataset=pd.read_csv(inputpath,sep=',', dtype={'a': str}, usecols= col_for_analysis, low_memory=False)


dataset.sort_values(by=["Year"], ascending=True, inplace=True)
print(dataset)
dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"] = dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"] = dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"].astype(int)
```

The end goal here, at least for now, is to sort everything by Year and then plot the "Year" column on the x-axis and the "Result Measure Value (ppt)" column on the y-axis. When I tried it initially, I was getting error messages indicating that the "Result Measure Value (ppt)" column contained NoneType values, so matplotlib couldn't plot it.
No big deal, I think to myself, I'll just use `dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"] = dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"].fillna(0, inplace=True)` to remove those NoneType values and replace them with a nice, hopefully plottable `0`.

That seemed to work. So I went on to try to change all the values in that column to int values, so they could all be plotted by matplotlib. I tried to do this by adding the line:

`dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"] = dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"].astype(int)`

That line of code throws the following, rather lengthy error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"] = dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"].astype(int)
  File "/home/runner/Fun-Public-Health-Project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5912, in astype
    new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/home/runner/Fun-Public-Health-Project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 419, in astype
    return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/home/runner/Fun-Public-Health-Project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 304, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Fun-Public-Health-Project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 580, in astype
    new_values = astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/home/runner/Fun-Public-Health-Project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 1292, in astype_array_safe
    new_values = astype_array(values, dtype, copy=copy)
  File "/home/runner/Fun-Public-Health-Project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 1237, in astype_array
    values = astype_nansafe(values, dtype, copy=copy)
  File "/home/runner/Fun-Public-Health-Project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 1154, in astype_nansafe
    return lib.astype_intsafe(arr, dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 668, in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Now, I thought that the line

```
dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"] = dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

would get rid of all NoneType values in the "Result Measure Value (ppt)" column by filling in any NoneType values with a 0. Am I wrong in thinking this? If so, how do I rid the column of NoneType values or otherwise get all the values in that column converted into something that I can work with to plot along with Year? Otherwise, how can I fix the code so that all values in this column can be converted to int and then plotted? Thanks!

Comment: With "inplace=True" "fillna" returns None.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either change it up "`inplace`":

```
dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Or assign it without the `inplace` argument:

```
dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"] = dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"].fillna(0)
```

But not both at the same time, since using the `inplace` argument makes it not return anything (`None`)

Comment: Thank you! I used the first method. It seems to have gotten rid of the initial error. Now I'm just getting an error that reads "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'".

Comment: Looks like there is a _'-'_ symbol somewhere in the data. Try using _.str.replace('-', '')_ before casting to int, like that:
_dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"] = dataset["Result Measure Value (ppt)"].str.replace('-', '').astype(int)_

Comment: Looks like that worked! Thanks, Aleksandrs!